# What is the correct way to proceed with this bool?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, boolean

I have this bool in my AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];

        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

        UIViewController *viewController = // determine the initial view controller here and instantiate it with [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:<storyboard id>];

        self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

        return YES;
    }
```

I'm getting an error on the *storyboard but what I am mainly trying to do is initialize the application in a different view controller than the main one. I have all the view controllers with IDs (such as the one I want to launch is named "Home"). How would I correctly write this bool if say my ViewController ID was home?

My main.m:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

The nil I get is whenever I try to go back to the original Home page from my Contact list page so it crashes and highlights the nil line. Both this and the above delegate bool are giving me issues. Any clarification would be very much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace?  Every crash has information needed to solve it.

Comment: Yes I can post as update. @trojanfoe

Comment: Do you have a file named: MainStoryboard.storyboard ?

Comment: Stop reposting questions. Edit your earlier post to clarify or add detail.

Comment: I don't think you understand at a certain point they stop responding and I am left stumped so you would understand why I am reposting. If you don't believe me go look at the other post. @Sjors what do you mean file named MainStoryboard.storyboard? The only storyboard name I have is Main.Storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];



    HomeController *viewController = // initialise it 

    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

or in the storyBoard just put the pointing arror to the view controller which you want to make as a root view controller.

Comment: I did that, its expecting the viewController to be named UIViewController for some reason and giving me the error. I pointed it to the root view as well but still giving me errors for some reason. But my main.m is giving me the real issues, if I launch my app it crashes because of the 

return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace explains what's wrong:

> - Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard
>     named 'MainStoryboard' in bundle NSBundle (loaded)' *

Your storyboard isn't called "MainStoryboard".

Comment: Thats exactly what I am trying to say, the entire storyboard containing all the view controllers is called Main.Storyboard but the one I want the app to launch on is on a view controller called "Home". I do not know how to fix it for it to do that, also I will update a link to a former answer on stack overflow about someone who had a similar question.

Comment: So the Home view controller is in the Main.storyboard? First of all, in UIStoryboard storyboardWithName, you have to pass in just "Main" as the storyboard name. Next, you want to get the Home VC from the storyboard by calling instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier on the storyboard object. Note that your Home view controller's identifier must be set in the view controller's identity inspector. Set both the storyboard ID and the restoration ID, which can be the same as the storyboard ID.

Comment: I have set both the storyboard ID as well as restoration ID of the home controller already and what do you mean when you say in UIStoryboard storyboardWithName?
Do you mean this line?
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

I change the "*storyboard" to Main or the "@"MainStoryboard"" to Main?

The reason I am trying to make it as Home is because I want to add a button called "Contacts" or bar button item, where someone could tap to access their contacts but I can't even get a root view from Home to the Contacts, is that part of it?

Comment: I mean that if your storyboard file is "Main.storyboard", the name that you pass to UIStoryboard storyboardWithName is just "Main", with no extension. I'm not sure what you mean by the last sentence.

Comment: Oh I replace "storyboardWithName" with "Main"? And in the last sentence I have a navigation controller named Home connected with my Contacts List View Controller and on the Home button I created a Bar button item named "Contacts" which would take it to the Contact List but when I connect it there is no root outlet option. Instead it says the push option is in parentheses depreciated, claiming its a nonadaptive action segue. Not sure how to fix that but would really appreciate it if you were able to continue helping me because I kind of got myself in a loophole here